# Resort the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following, and then I would like like to resort the array to its original state with the out come being posted to console.log. But I'm getting a bit lost on what direction to take:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var cards=new Array(
            'clu01',
            'clu02',
            'clu03',
            'clu04',
            'clu05',
            'clu06',
            'clu07',
            'clu08',
            'clu09',
            'clu10',
            'clu11',
            'clu12',
            'clu13',
            'dia01',
            'dia02',
            'dia03',
            'dia04',
            'dia05',
            'dia06',
            'dia07',
            'dia08',
            'dia09',
            'dia10',
            'dia11',
            'dia12',
            'dia13',
            'hea01',
            'hea02',
            'hea03',
            'hea04',
            'hea05',
            'hea06',
            'hea07',
            'hea08',
            'hea09',
            'hea10',
            'hea11',
            'hea12',
            'hea13',
            'spa01',
            'spa02',
            'spa03',
            'spa04',
            'spa05',
            'spa06',
            'spa07',
            'spa08',
            'spa09',
            'spa10',
            'spa11',
            'spa12',
            'spa13'
        );

        function Shuffle(o) {
            for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
            return o;
        };

        Shuffle(cards);

        console.log(cards);
});
```

Comment: And what's the original sort order? Alphabetic?

Comment: Just make a copy of the array before shuffling.

Comment: ^^ what he said, just do `var cards2 = cards.slice(0)` and you'll keep the original array.

Comment: The original order is what the current Array is. Can you show an example in my code of what you mean? - I'm at a lost with this, think I've gone code blind. lol

Answer (score 0):

If the original array is sorted alphbetically, you can just do a `sort()`

```
cards.sort()
```

You can also define a custom sorting function:

```
cards.sort( function(a, b) {
    // some logic to compare 2 values to see which goes first
    // return 1 if a comes after b
    // return -1 if a comes before b
    // return 0 if they are the same (this usually means whichever came first will be first)
});
```

Comment: But yea, you're probably better off making a copy of the array before you shuffled it as mentioned in the comments of OP

Answer (score 0):

The way I do things like this is having a separate array of indices, the same length of your array. So, for example for

```
var cards = ['clu01', 'clu02','clu03'];
```

you create

```
var indices = [0, 1, 2];
```

Now, when you do your shuffle, you compare your original array, but shuffle the indices array. So essentially, you are shuffling the positions in the array but not the elements themselves. That way you keep both separate and can access both states at any time without much overhead.

To access shuffled:

```
cards[indices[i]];
```

To access original:

```
cards[i];
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Any chance you could put an example in my code? Sorry I'm on a bit of a learning curve with this, so its all good practice. Cheers.

Comment: That's all there is to it. Instead of calling `Shuffle(cards)` call `Shuffle(indices)` and then whenever you need to access a shuffled position read it through the indices array `cards[indices[i]]`

Comment: Still lost with this :\

Answer (score 0):

With the time and headache you are going to have in resorting your cards, you might as well have two array, your source "sorted" array, and your shuffled array. When you want to sort your array just use your source array. When you want to shuffle an array you can either reshuffle the "shuffled" array, or make a copy of the source and shuffle that.

The war is already won you can already shuffle cards.

Answer (score 0):

```
var orig_cards = cards.slice(0);
Shuffle(cards);
console.log(cards);
cards = orig_cards;
console.log(cards);
```